# How to centralised two labels with Auto layout in superview?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have one label with fixed width and the second one is the variable length according to the text.
I just want to centralize both of the labels in the super view (UIView).

Please let me know how to achieve this with auto layout. 
Thanks

Comment: Center how? Side-by-side, both together centered?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let try view structure like the above image:

Parent view is orange part in the image.
You have 2 labels: FixLength and VariableLength and want to centralize both of them. My solution is adding 2 labels on another view (ViewContainer) and centralizing ViewContainer on ParentView. Needed constraints are

1.ViewContainer

- Align center X to supper view
- Align center Y to supper view
- Content hugging priority 250 - 250
- Content compression Resistant priority: 250 - 250

2.FixedLength:

- Leading space to supper view: 0
- Top space to supper view: 0
- Width equals: 50 (or any value you want)
- Height equals: 20 (or any value you want)

3.VariableLength

- Bottom space to supper view: 0
- Top space to supper view: 0
- Trailing space to supper view: 0
- Leading space to FixedLength: 10 (or any value you want)
- Content hugging priority: 750 - 750
- Content compression Resistant priority: 750 - 750

The most important part here is: content hugging priority and content compression resistant priority in VariableLength must be higher than in ViewContainer

After adding constraints, if the layout have some warnings, just update frame to remove warning (but still keep the constraints)

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it's work for me. Hope this help!